# Display image as background in Flask

Tags: python, html, rest, flask

I am giving my first steps on flask applications.
I would like to know how to show this image as a background and the html text on top?

[image]

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "<h1>Welcome to the API Service</h1><p>This site is a prototype API for displaying dashboards: quick_report, crime_locator.</p>"


app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most elegant way to solve it, using the templates.
First step is to create a **static** and **templates** directory, like this:

```
--static
    |
    -- image.png
-- templates
   |
   -- index.html
--app.py
```

index.html

```
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("/static/image.png");
}
</style>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to the API Service</h1>
<p>This site is a prototype API for displaying dashboards: quick_report,crime_locator.</p>

</body>
```

app.py

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__, static_folder="static")
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
   return flask.render_template('index.html')

app.run()
```